# Best practices for managing workarounds (for broken data)

Tags: data-mining, data-conversion, data-quality

I have to work with government-provided data that is sometimes broken in strange ways. My code already contains snippets like:

```
for row in governmental_data:
    # XXX Workaround for that one row among thousands
    # that was mislabeled by a clerk and will not be fixed
    # before form A-320-Tango-5 is completed and submitted
    # on the first Sunday after a solstice.
    if row is the_spawn_of_satan:
        row = fix_row_A320(row)
    # XXX end of workaround
    process_row(row)
```

which before the error was just

```
for row in governmental_data:
    process_row(row)
```

I can not make a mirror of the data with applied fixes, because the data is dynamic.

What can I do to manage these workarounds as they grow in number? Are there any best practices (besides "do not provide broken data to begin with")?

Comment: Real data is messy. So A) live with preprocessing and filtering -- it is usually okay to skip broken records -- or B) use algorithms that are robust to such errors in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use [Decorator Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) for handling this data conversion issue. [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Second_Example_.28coffee_making_scenario.29) 
has a coffee making example. In the same way I suggest every data conversion should be decorator which takes a row and makes some operations on it and gives back a row. This design pattern is well established one. Intercepting filters design pattern is similar to this idea which is implemented both in java ([servlet filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)) and .net ([Asp.Net Mvc Filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)).

Your code should be as following

```
listOfDataConversionFilters = [XXXWorkaround,formA_320Tango5,...]
for row in governmental_data:
    for filter in listOfDataConversionFilters
        filteredRow = filter(row)
    process_row(filteredRow)
```

Comment: Filters should be allowed to skip rows IMHO.